# How to autogenerate ids Using annotations in Hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate

I want to create table of product in which i can save product id as primary key , and second table there is category table in this table there is the `catid` as primary key,but  problem is both Generate  Key In Fashion of 1,2,3,4 mans both have Same column ,How to generate key likes `PID001,PI002.....` and `CATID001` `,CATID002`

Comment: Why don't you use conventional Number Id and modify it when you want to display it to user. Number IDs are far more optimal when compared to String IDs

Comment: Of course they are separate tables and you don't need to worry about 1,2,3,4.... they won't conflict. However, when you want to display IDs, you can concat string as required.

Answer (score 2):

In this case you should use custom id generator strategy.

For Custom Id generation we need to implement `IdentifierGenerator` interface and need to provide the body of *generate* method.

IdentifierGenerator have method `generate` so you need to provide the body of it.

Here is an [example of custom id  generator strategy](https://github.com/techguy-bhushan/kickhibernate/tree/master/src/main/java/com/kickwithhibernate/generatorclassesinhibernate/customgenerator).

Comment: Please consider editing your code to show a java annotations example instead of forcing the reader to go to the link you provide.

Comment: @Gray ok i will, Thank you!